# Loop that can take user input every time through

Tags: c

How can I make a loop that can take user input every time it loops?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORD "jumble"
#define JUMBLED "mleujb"

int main()
{
    char string[6];
    int i = 0;
    printf("The jumbled word is ");
    printf(JUMBLED);
    printf("\nCan you guess the original: ");
    while(i == 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", string);
        if (string == "exit")
        {
            return;
        }
        if(string == WORD)
        {
            i++;
            printf("Kudos! You've guessed the word!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("English please, good sir. Guess again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

What I had hoped for was that every time the program went through the loop, it would want a new input with the scanf function. However, that apparently does not work that way. Instead, the program takes the value of the first scanf and uses it over and over again. If it is the wrong word, it will have an infinite loop.

This program has more than a few bugs in it: for instance, it does not actually compare the input to the actual word yet. As that does not pertain to the question, it is not my immediate concern.

Comment: can you explain what happens?

Comment: Your code isn't compilable as is (semicolons missing, invalid statments), and also please use correct indentation and don't put closing braces right next to another statement. Makes your code harder to read. :)

Comment: it takes the original input and uses it again in the loop, essentially making an infinite loop if it is wrong

Comment: have you used `scanf` before?

Comment: @birryree sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: @ruslik in the code or in general? in the code, that is the first place that scanf appears

Comment: @not_l33t, I think @ruslik means 'in general'. `scanf` is pretty...finicky, and its behavior can really stump the unfamiliar. Can you tell us exactly what you were doing (and posting the code you do have would be really nice too)? You are likely running into one of `scanf`'s awesome behaviors, like not consuming the newline because it is not part of its format string.

Comment: @not_l33t - now that you have posted code, I have to point out you can not do `==` equality checks on `char` arrays and string literals and expect it to do what you want in C. They will compare addresses of their first letters. You want to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` from `<string.h>`

Comment: your code just made me realize you should first work with the identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code for helping you precisely is not great
Also can you define a bit better your question ? you don't really say what is going wrong

but here is my guess

your test is i ==0 which means as soon as your user inputs the right word your exiting your loop...

I would guess your looking for something like

```
exit_condition = 0;

while (exit_condition == 0)
{

   read keyboard entry

    if(condition to exit loop)
    {

        exit_condition = 1;
        printf("correct")
    }
    else
    {
        printf("try again")
    }

}
```

Concerning the tests I think you need to read up  bit on input and tests

try this

http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student1.html

Comment: from what i understand, it will still finish running through until it gets to the end. that is, even if the value of i changes before the end of the if, c will still have the program finish the if statement, then jump back up to check if the while statement is still true

Comment: yes it will execute to the end, what you seem to missing here is that in your code as soon as your enter the right answer your exiting the loop. As I said your not very clear on what you want to do so I proposed a answer without fully understand your problem. are you trying to get a loop that keeps asking to enter a number as long as the user doesn't input the right answer ? do you want the user to input a series of answers ...

Comment: what i am going for is that if the user enters the wrong word, the loop should start over and input should be taken again

Answer (score 2):

you are using `scanf()` wrongly instead of `scanf("%d",string)` use `scanf("%s",string)` as %d is used for decimal input and %s is used for string input

Answer (score 1):

1. scanf is incorrect for getting input string. It should be scanf("%s", string) as pointed out by others
2. String comparison cannot be done by using == in 'C'. It will only compare the address of two strings which will fail. Use 'strncmp' function instead.